# How to let a column accept null values as zero (0) in Self-Relation table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, foreign-key-relationship

[image]

As described in the image, I got a `parent-Children relation` and since the `ParentID` not accepting null values (and I can't change to nullabel due to some restriction in the UI I have), how can I remove an existence relation between ReportDataSources in order to change the parent for them (here i want to set the parentId for one of them = 0) how could i do that since `i cant change the ParentID directly` and setting `Parent = null` is not valid

```
public void SetReportDataSourceAsMaster(ReportDataSource reportDataSource)
{
    //Reset Master
    this.ReportDataSources.ToList().ForEach(rds => rds.IsMaster = false);
    //Set Master
    reportDataSource.IsMaster = true;
    //Set Parent ID for the rest of the Reports data sources
    this.ReportDataSources.Where(rds => rds.ID != reportDataSource.ID).ToList().ForEach(rds =>
    {
        //Change Parent ID
        rds.Parent = reportDataSource;
        //Remove filttering data
        rds.FilteringDataMembers.Clear();
        //Remove Grouping Data
        rds.GroupingDataMembers.Clear();
    });
    //Delete parent HERE THE EXCEPTION THROWN AFTER CALLING SUBMITCHANGES()
    reportDataSource.Parent = null;
}
```

Exception thrown after calling `SubmitChanges()`:

> An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a ReportDataSource and a ReportDataSource. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (ReportDataSource.ParentID) cannot be set to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you make your root element be its own parent? You would have to check it each time you want to recursively find an element ancestor (to avoid unending loops), but I think it would work fine for you.

Comment: +1 Im testing this solution now, and if there is any trick i can do in LINQ avoiding the `selfParent` setting would be better

Comment: I agree this is just a workaround and not a real solution. But my competences with databases are not sufficient ofr me to propose anything else, so...